# Prove that$\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}/{\frac{\Gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)}}$ is decreasing function.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to prove that

$\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}/{\frac{\Gamma(n,n)}{\Gamma(n)}}$

this function is decreasing function for n $\geq$ 1

where $\Gamma(n,n) = \int_n^\infty t^{n-1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d} t$ is the upper incomplete gamma function.

I tried it differentiating, but it is very tricky to handle.

So, I wish anyone's answer or advice or suggestion to help to access this problem.

Comment: the function can be simplified to $\frac{\Gamma(n+1,n+1)}{n\Gamma(n,n)}$

Comment: Yeah I know, but this form is also not simple

Comment: just an idea: try to write the lower incomplete gamma as a finite sum after iterated integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(n)=\dfrac{\Gamma (n,n)}{\Gamma (n)}$

Our function is $g(n)=\dfrac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=\dfrac{\Gamma (n+1,n+1)}{n\, \Gamma (n,n)}$

The function is decreasing if $g(n+1)<g(n),\;\forall n\ge 1$

That is if $\dfrac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}<1$

Observe that for $n\ge 1$ we have $\Gamma (n,n)<\Gamma (n) $ thus
$$\frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}=\frac{n \Gamma (n,n) \Gamma (n+2,n+2)}{(n+1) \Gamma (n+1,n+1)^2}<\frac{n \Gamma (n) \Gamma (n+2)}{(n+1) \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$
Consider now integer $n$. The previous relation becomes
$$\frac{n (n-1)! (n+1)!}{(n+1) (n!)^2}=1$$

If it is true for integers then it is true for all $n\ge 1$

Hope this helps

Comment: Why the last inequality is accomplished? if we use $gamma(n,n) < gaama(n)$, numeraator gets larger but the denominator also gets larger